# How to generate rows for time

Tags: mysql

How to generate rows for calendar_time using mysql select query ?

My ouput has to be like the below format and it has to generate 1440 rows.

```
0000
0001
0002
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like following

1. create a mysql table with only one field type - int
2. create a mysql function which will give you the desired output
3. execute function each time to get each unique id from the function

for more information please look at this

http://www.sblog.in/2014-04-08-16-42-36/mysql/90-example-on-how-to-generate-zero-fill-auto-incremented-id-in-mysql